# React-native ListItem and ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a background Image using ImageBackground, from 'react-native', but when i use ListItem, from 'react-native-elements', the ListItem cover the background image. It's possible to use both?

I tried with Flat List, but since i use ListItem inside it's the same problem.

Comment: just make sure `ImageBackground` is on the outermost layer:  `<ImageBackground><ListItem /> </ImageBackground>`

Comment: When i do that @displayname, the image does not appear, do you think it's because the ListItem has a default color wich cover the image?

Comment: i dont think ListItem has a default color. Have you tried giving the ImageBackground `flex:1, width:'100%', height:'100%' ` ?